# changing margin-top of element while scrolling ,javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to attach an element to the bottom of a navbar
the navbar is fixed so so it will be in the top when i scroll
the problem is how to change the margin-top of that element so its top will be the bottom of the nav bar .. and its bottom is fixed .. (it will be hidden if i scoll a lot ) so the heigth of this element will be smaller when i scroll

here is what i did

```
 $(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    $('.imagebleu').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / 500));
    $('.imagebleu').css('margin-top', ($('.navbar').heigh()+$(document).scrollTop()));
});
```

if you need more code i will post it 
here is the link for the page

```
  http://rechmed.byethost9.com/android_connect/
```

[image]

the part that contain that text is the nav bar 
and the other part is the .imagebleu element
they have the same opacity , but because this element is under the navbar 
the navbar opacity doesn't look the same with it

So i want to add margin that changes by scrolling to fix this element on the bottom of the navbar

thank you very much

Comment: `$(.navbar).heigh()` should be `$('.navbar').height()` for a start.

Comment: sorry your right , i wrote it directly here.. my mistake

Comment: i fixed it without js .. just with position:absolute; and z-index:2000; hhhh biggest as possible

Comment: Then please put an answer with this and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

i did a solution based on layers (with z-index)

```
.imagebleu {
    background-color: #3498db;
    border-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0; 
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:50px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0; 
  z-index:3;
}
```

the margin-top:50px this is the heigh pf the navbar ,so this element will be right under the nav bar : 0px between them

position fixed this made the element cover all the page, so i added z-index
to make the element between the content of page and the paralax image

something like :

```
 navbar>content>this element>paralaximage  (the z-index)
```

the the element when scrolling will hide the parallax image, and the content hide the "element"(.imagebleu) ,but no one hide the navbar

i will update the website so you can see the difference

```
  rechmed.byethost9.com/android_connect
```